# Value of sine in trigonometry ratio

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $\sin 37^\circ$
without using table or calculator.

I've tried using Taylor's series,
but I will still need calculator.
Please  help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: are sure it is $$37^{\circ}$$?

Comment: exactly sir,it is

Comment: And exactly why do you need to find this without table or calculator? And if you got its value, then what would you do with it? I would really like to know.

Comment: Do you need the exact value or an approximation?

Comment: I need exact value @king

Comment: Okay, using "table or calculator" will not give you exact value, since it is not a rational number. So why do you "need exact value"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want approximation, this would work :

$$\sin 37^{\circ} \approx \sin 36^{\circ} =\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt 5}}{4}$$

For evaluating this without using calculator, we need to perform a few calculation,

Since it's very easy to see that $45^2=2025$, we have $$4.5^2=20.25$$
And hence $$\sqrt{20} \approx 4.5$$

Now we've $$10- 2\sqrt 5 = 10-\sqrt{20} \approx 5.5$$

We can easily see that $550$ is nearly half way between $23^2$ and $24^2$. Therefore $$\sqrt{550} \approx 23.5 \implies \sqrt{5.5} \approx 2.35$$

We're almost done now.

$$\sin 36^{\circ} = \frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt 5}}{4} \approx \frac{2.35}{4} = 0.5875$$

(The actual value of $\sin 36^{\circ} \approx 0.58778 !$)

Since $\sin 37^{\circ}$ is slightly greater than $\sin {36}^{\circ}$, you can take $$\sin 37^{\circ} \approx 0.6$$

(The actual value of $\sin 37^{\circ} \approx 0.6018!$)

Comment: But how are we going to evaluate that without using a calculator or table or an hour with a few pieces of paper?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat You can see my edit.

Comment: But if the precision is only up to 2dp why don't we just use the good old right triangle?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat OP probably doesn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you are not really looking at an exact value, you can try constructing a triangle with sides of $3,4,5$ units. The angle is actually $36.87^\circ$ but is very close to $37^\circ$.

So we have $\sin37^\circ\approx0.6$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can say it's equal to $\cos 53^{\circ}$, but that's probably not what you need.

[There are analytical expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Explicit_values) for $\sin 36^{\circ}$ and $\sin 1^{\circ}$ that you can use, along with $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$ and the addition formula to get $\sin 37^{\circ}$, but it's an *awfully* nasty expression ...

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my best guess.

Consider a regular pentagon inscribed inside a unit circle

[image]

If we average the coordinates of the vertices we will get the center of the circle.

or

$2\cos 144 + 2\cos 72  + 1 = 0\\
4\cos^2 72 + 2 \cos 72 - 1 = 0\\
\cos 72 = \frac {\sqrt {5} - 1}{4}\\
\cos 144 = \frac {- \sqrt {5}-1 }{4}\\
\cos 36 =  \frac {\sqrt {5}+1 }{4}\\
\sin 36 = \sqrt {1-\cos^2 36} = \sqrt {\frac {5-\sqrt 5}{8}}\\
\sin 37 = \sin 36\cos 1 + \cos 36\sin 1\\
\cos 1 \approx  1\\
\sin 1 \approx \frac {\pi}{180}\\
\sin 37 \approx \sqrt {\frac {5-\sqrt 5}{8}} + \frac {\sqrt {5}+1 }{4}(\frac {\pi}{180})$

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @Jaideep Khare is good but I wouldn't conclude as he does, because the error done is approximately $0.015$, which is rather high.

A much better precision can be obtained. Here is how:

Using his formula $\sin(36°)=\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt 5}}{4}$, I advise to compute

$$\cos(36°)=\sqrt{1-\sin(36°)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{6+2\sqrt 5}}{4},$$

and then use the first 2 terms of Taylor expansion of $\sin$ function around $36°$ (you mentionned that you have attempted such an expansion):

$$\tag{1}\sin(36°+1°) \ \approx \ \sin(36°) \ + \ 1° \times \cos(36°)...$$

with $1°$ replaced by $\pi/180$ (conversion degrees $\to$ radians).

Can you do the corresponding calculation ?

I find in this way $\approx 0.60190$, the true value being $0.60181$.

Thus the error is $\approx 10^4$, which very small.

Remark : I haven't addressed the easyness of calculation by hand. Jaideep Khare has done it.

Remark: The beginning of Taylor expansion could be obtained in a plain way by using addition formula :

$$\sin(36°+1°) \ = \ \sin(36°) \  \underbrace{\cos(1°)}_{\approx 1} \  + \  \underbrace{\sin(1°)}_{\approx 1°} \ \cos(36°).$$

Comment: You can take a look at my edit. It's much better, now.